# Can't get Ninject Interception to work with WCF

Tags: wcf, ninject, ninject-extensions, ninject-interception

we're switching from UNITY to Ninject as our default service locator for WCF services. There's a beautiful NuGet package available for doing this and getting the standard resolution up-and-running is a breeze.

However - I want to intercept the calls to my WCF service. Here's what I've got:

My svc file:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="NinjectWcfApp.Service1" Factory="Ninject.Extensions.Wcf.NinjectServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Here's my service:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{


   [Inject]
    public ISomeManager Manager { get; set; }


public string GetData(int value)
{
    if(this.Manager != null)
        this.Manager.DoStuff();


    return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
}

}
```

Kernel is built up like this:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<ISomeManager>().To<SomeManager>();
    kernel.Bind<IService1>().To<Service1>().Intercept().With<MyInterceptor>();
}
```

If I setup the kernel like this, the manager instance is injected, but there's no interception taking place. My interceptor that logs something before execution and after execution is never invoked.

Other Stackoverflow threads suggest using:

```
    kernel.Bind<Service1>().ToSelf().Intercept().With<MyInterceptor>();
```

If I do that, the manager is not being injected. If I then go ahead and create a constructor which takes in the manager, it works, but again: no interception.

```
    kernel.Bind<Service1>().ToSelf().WithConstructorArgument("manager", kernel.Get<ISomeManager>()).Intercept().With<MyInterceptor>();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Any methods which are intercepted must be virtual:

```
    public virtual string GetData(int value)
```